# GitHub Actions Matrix strategy

Tags: github-actions

I created a matrix strategy jobs for 5 applications but on the slack notification I’m getting all five application status, I want to only receive alert on the workflow status not on individual jobs status, how can I do this?

Comment: You could create another job to send the notification, that would run in sequence of the current one using the matrix strategy.

Comment: I’m using reusable workflow, where I have the slack notification  as a step in a job on the called workflow. Do I add it inside the caller workflow instead under another job, I have the strategy matrix in the caller workflow as a job

Comment: It depends. So you want the notification to be related to the reusable workflow conclusion, or to be related to the main workflow conclusion? If it's the later, you should add the job in the main workflow. Otherwise, on the reusable one.

Comment: I added it to reusable workflow at first, it was sending alerts for all jobs to slack, now I added the slack notifications job to the main workflow as a job but now it’s not even giving me any alert in slack. Don’t know what could be wrong.

Comment: It would be easier to help you by sharing both workflow implementations (the main and reusable one0